# Premiere Pro Install error P205

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, adobe-premiere, adobe-creative-cloud

I was trying to install Adobe Premiere Pro CC earlier today. My computer is connected to a WiFi network (I have tried multiple as well as wired), goes through a domain (I can't change that) and uses a firewall (tried turning it off).

When I start the installer, it asks for the Admin password like usual. I then sign in to my account successfully, and the installer starts. It remains on 0% for a long time (like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WprW7.png)) before seeming to time out and give this error message: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rYCk.png) - with code P205. I have tried many different online guides and forum replies to fix this as well as the Adobe support page, but none had any effect.

Does anyone know how to fix this please? Thanks. (btw I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro)

Comment: [Creative Cloud App, installation error code 205](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1453807). Are you using a proxy that could be interfering? Did you install it successfully before using the same network?

Comment: @Seth I don't have a proxy. I haven't yet installed it successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to install PP in a domain account. While it had the right privileges, the download did not work. I had to switch to a local, admin account and then the install worked.

Answer (score 0):

Error 205 mean the download is broken. You can try to change the browser you use and download it again. You can try also to reset the cache of your browser and try to download again. Also run OS in Safe mode with networking and try again.

Check [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1453807) and [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/download-update-errors.html) for reference

Comment: I tried it but there is no difference - the error is still there